# non trivial relationship in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

i get:

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

code of model:

```
class Order extends Model{

  public function order_status(){
    $q = self::GetQueryWithCurrentOrderStatus();
    return $q->where('order.id', '=', $this->id)->get();
  }






     private static function GetQueryWithCurrentOrderStatus(){

    $rawSql = OrderOrderStatus::selectRaw('order_order_status.order_id as id, max(created_at)')->groupBy('order_order_status.order_id')->toSql();

    $query = OrderStatus::join('order_order_status', 'order_order_status.order_status_id', '=', 'order_status.id')
      ->join('order', 'order.id', '=', 'order_order_status.order_id')
      ->join(DB::raw('( ' . $rawSql . ') CurrentOrderStatus'), function ($join) {
        $join->on('order_order_status.id', '=', 'CurrentOrderStatus.id');
      });
    return $query;

  }
}
```

db structure is written in the answer here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151193/good-database-structure-for-scenario-with-orders-that-have-a-state-and-the-state/151195#151195

`order_status_history` is `order_order_status`

now i could write in the blade file just:

`$order->order_status()` instead of `$order->order_status` ... but why? is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to call a method, call a method.  `order_status` isn't a property.

If you access it as a property, it requires an Eloquent relationship (like it says) which are created through the hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo, belongsToMany methods: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships